# Cómo imprimir una serie de números que tienen secuencia y los que no separarlos por coma

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un rango de numero inventario de muebles por llamarlos de esta manera y se tienen que asignar a una “orden de envió”, estos números cuentan con un estatus de disponibilidad, el cual cambia al ejecutarse la siguiente consulta;

```
UPDATE `inventario` SET id_orden_envio=9, estatus='EN ENVIO' WHERE clave_mueble=23 AND estatus='DISPONIBLE' LIMIT 8
```

Donde de un listado de numeros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces la consulta tomaría los numero de inventario 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23,27, (los números no están de manera consecutiva porque talvez en algún momento esa orden de envío fue cancelada y esos numero volvieron a estar disponibles).
Entonces la consulta en PHP arroja los números que fueron asignados  cuando se hizo UPDATE

```
$query_inventario = $mysqli-> query (“SELECT * FROM inventario_muebles”);
while ($inf_articulo_inventario = mysqli_fetch_array($query_inventario)) {
    echo ‘NUMERO DE INVENTARIO ’. .$inf_articulo_inventario[‘Numero_inventario’].’<br> ’;
}
```

De tal manera que imprime :

```
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 15
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 16
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 17
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 18
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 19
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 20
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 23
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 27
```

Mi problema es que necesito imprimir los números que si son consecutivos o tienen alguna secuencia separados por  “ AL “ y los números que no tienen una secuencia separados por una coma por ejemplo:

```
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 15 AL 20 y 23,27
```

O si fuera mas en serie debería imprimir por ejemplo :

```
NUMERO DE INVENTARIO 15 AL 20 y 23,27 y 30 AL 35
```

Lo he intentado con php range pero no me funciona porque agrega los números faltantes de esa serie o rango

Si pudieran ayudarme por favor

- Agrego el código de como encuentro si el número tiene alguna secuencia. Ahora el problema es que si después de los números que si tienen secuencia los reconoce como si no tuviera un secuencia. Esto lo realizo cargando a un arreglo los números de inventario

```
$array = array (15,16,17,18,19,20,23,27,40,41,43,44);
$secuencia = $array [0];
foreach ($array as $valor_numero) {
    if ($secuencia == $valor_numero) {
        echo 'si secuencial '.$valor_numero.'<br>';
    } elseif ($secuencia != $valor_numero) {
        echo 'no secuencial '.$valor_numero.'<br>';
    }
    $secuencia = $secuencia + 1;
}
```

Comment: Dices que lo has intentado con php range, pero no has puesto el código. Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta las veces que necesites pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece a pie de la pregunta para agregar lo que te falte. En este caso te falta agregar lo que has intentado, pues tal como está puesta ahora la pregunta es una tarea que nos encomiendas pues no demuestras que hayas intentado nada, lo siento.

Comment: @masterguru, mi problema con php range es que solo estaba colocando el numero inicial de la serie y el final sin importar si entonces por ejemplo tomando el numero de inventario 15 como principio y el 27 como final PHP range componía la serie del 15,16,17....25,26,27 , agrego a la pregunta como identifico si lleva una secuencia o no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba este código a ver si te sirve:

```php
// valores de ejemplo
$numeros_inventario = [8,10,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,25,27,30,31,32,33,34,35,45,67,69,70,72,73,75,77,79,81,85,86,87,88,90];

// valores iniciales
$anterior       = null;
$salida         = '';
$numero_ciclo   = 0;
$total_numeros  = count($numeros_inventario);
$rango_terminado  = false;

// bucle
foreach ($numeros_inventario as $numero_inventario) {
    // incrementamos numero de ciclo
    $numero_ciclo++;
    if (is_null($anterior)) {
        // Primer ciclo. Inicializamos variables
        $anterior       = $numero_inventario;
        $inicio_rango   = $numero_inventario;
    } else {
        // realizamos cálculos
        $salida_vacia       = empty($salida);
        $hay_final_rango    = isset($final_rango);
        $ciclo_final        = ($numero_ciclo == $total_numeros) ? true : false;
        $es_consecutivo     = ($numero_inventario == $anterior + 1) ? true : false;

        // verificamos los casos posibles
        switch (true) {
            // en caso que sea consecutivo
            case ($es_consecutivo):
                // reseteamos valor del final de rango, por si acaso lo es después
                $final_rango    = $numero_inventario;
                $salida         .= ($ciclo_final) ?
                    // si es el último ciclo lo agregamos a la salida.
                    " y DEL ".$inicio_rango." AL ".$final_rango :
                    // sino no agregamos nada
                    '';
                break;

            // en caso que no sea consecutivo pero estemos calculando un rango
            case !$es_consecutivo and $hay_final_rango:
                if ($salida_vacia) {
                    // Si es el primer caso de la salida
                    $salida .= "DEL ".$inicio_rango." AL ".$final_rango;
                } else {
                    $salida .= ($ciclo_final) ?
                        // si es ciclo final se agrega rango y número de inventario actual a la salida
                        " y DEL ".$inicio_rango." AL ".$final_rango." y ".$numero_inventario :
                        // sino solo el ciclo
                        " y DEL ".$inicio_rango." AL ".$final_rango;
                }
                // vaciamos la variable pues ya se terminó este rango
                unset($final_rango);
                // establecemos este número como el inicio de otro posible rango
                $inicio_rango       = $numero_inventario;
                // salimos de un rango terminado
                $rango_terminado  = true;
                break;

            // en caso que no sea consecutivo y no estemos calculando un rango
            case !$es_consecutivo and !$hay_final_rango:
                if ($rango_terminado == true) {
                    // si venimos de un rango terminado agregar la "y"
                    $salida .= ($ciclo_final) ?
                        // si es ciclo final agrego anterior y actual
                        " y ".$anterior.",".$numero_inventario :
                        // sino agrego anterior solo
                        " y ".$anterior;
                } else {
                    // si no venimos de un rango terminado...
                    if ($ciclo_final) {
                        // si es ciclo final agrego anterior y actual para terminar la salida
                        $salida .= ",".$anterior.",".$numero_inventario;
                    } else {
                        // si no es ciclo final...
                        $salida .= ($salida_vacia) ?
                            // si es el primer caso de la salida lo ponemos sin coma
                            $anterior :
                            // sino con coma
                            ",".$anterior;
                    }
                }
                // ya no salimos de un rango terminado
                $rango_terminado = false;
                // establecemos este número como el inicio de otro posible rango
                $inicio_rango = $numero_inventario;
                break;
        }
        // reseteamos valor para el siguiente ciclo
        $anterior       = $numero_inventario;
    }
}
echo $salida;
// 8,10,13 y DEL 15 AL 20 y 23,25,27 y DEL 30 AL 35 y 45,67 y DEL 69 AL 70 y DEL 72 AL 73 y 75,77,79,81 y DEL 85 AL 88 y 90
```

He puesto comentarios en el código para que se entienda lo que se va haciendo. No creo que merezca ninguna explicación adicional, simplemente leer bien los comentarios para entender la lógica de la respuesta.

Comment: si me sirve, lo que estaba realizando era guardar  en un tabla los numeros que si tienen secuencia y los que no guardarlos separados por coma, para luego encontrar el min y el max pero creo tampoco funcionaria de la manera correcta, muchas gracias!, lo implemetare

Comment: Vale, perfecto, otro dia lo documento y mejoro un poco, que lo he hecho de pasadilla sin optimizarlo demasiado y probando todos los casos que se me ocurrian, y despues lo documento mejor, que ahora esta hecho unos zorros, jeje, pero es que no me queda tiempo ahora mismo para eso. Saludos!

Comment: michisimas gracias!!! se me paso comentar que los números de inventarios consta de 7 dígitos los cuales a la derecha de componen de ceros por ejemplo 0000010 o 001578 para implementar tu código quitare los ceros con substr(), eres un tipaso amigo nuevamente gracias!

Comment: Bueno, he actualizado y optimizado un poco el código y he puesto comentarios para que en cada punto se sepa lo que está pasando. Saludos!!

Comment: hermano hace un tiempo me orientaste y enseñaste como se realizaba esta practica intente volver a implementar tu codigo en un ciclo con un while  donde hay mas clave_mueble y cada mueble que entra en la consulta mysql  digamos que el que tiene la clave 22 genera un arreglo y termina con un numero en el siguiente mueble que genera su arreglo de inventario me agrega el ultimo numero en la variable de anterior he intentado limpiarla de nuevo pero no logro que se resete la declaro com null de nuevo pero sigue cargando ese numero del arreglo anterior que no pertenece, podrias orientarme de favor

Comment: tendria que resetear la varable porque digamos que el arreglo es [1,2,3,7,8] cuando se genera el nuevo a reglo del siguiente tipo de mueble agrega [8,10,11,12,70,80] donde el 8 es de el arreglo anterior

Answer (score 0):

te planteo otra solución: En este caso la primera parte se encarga de dividir el array inicial en un grupo de arrays, que contienen los elementos que son consecutivos.

```
$list = [8,10,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,25,27,30,31,32,33,34,35,45,67,69,70,72,73,75,77,79,81,85,86,87,88,90];

$sequences = function($element, $index, $collection) {
    if($index === 0) return true;
    return ($element -1) === $collection[ $index -1 ];

};

$aggregation = [];
$seq = 0;
foreach ($list as $index => $element) {
    $result = $sequences($element, $index, $list);
    if(!$result) $seq++;
    $aggregation[$seq][] = $element;
}


//print_r($aggregation);
```

En este print_r, verias un resultado tal que:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 16
        [2] => 17
        [3] => 18
        [4] => 19
        [5] => 20
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 25
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 27
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 30
        [1] => 31
        [2] => 32
        [3] => 33
        [4] => 34
        [5] => 35
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 67
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 69
        [1] => 70
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 72
        [1] => 73
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => 75
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => 77
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 79
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 81
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 85
        [1] => 86
        [2] => 87
        [3] => 88
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 90
    )
```

)

Es decir, tendrias en cada key (del 0 al 17) un array que contiene todos los elementos secuenciales de tu listado. En caso de que tenga un elemento, es porque no es secuencial con los anteriores.

Después recorremos ese array, y componemos la cadena que quieres mostrar por salida. En este caso, defino las clásicas variables para saber si estamos en la primera iteración del bucle, la ultima o en el loop. Según eso, vamos a componer grupos de 'del X al Y', o con comas separadas.

Si un grupo de secuencia tiene mas de un elemento, seleccionamos solo el primero y el ultimo de la secuencia (para formar el grupo 'del X al Y') con el implode.

```
$string = "";

foreach($aggregation as $key => $items) {
    $first = $key === 0;
    $last = $key === count($aggregation) - 1;
    $loop = !$first && !$last;
    
    $hasMoreThan1Element = count($items) > 1;
    $elements = $hasMoreThan1Element
                ? [$items[0], $items[count($items) -1]]
                : [$items[0]];
                
    $elementsSeparator = $hasMoreThan1Element
                ? ' al '
                : '';
                
    if($first) {
        $string = implode($elementsSeparator, $elements);
    }
    
    if($loop) {
        $start = $hasMoreThan1Element
                 ? ' y del '
                 : ', ';

        $string.= $start . implode($elementsSeparator, $elements);
    }
    
    if($last) {
        $start = $hasMoreThan1Element
             ? ' y del '
             : ' y ';
             
        $string .=  $start . implode($elementsSeparator, $elements);
   }
    
}

print_r($string);
```

el ultimo print te presenta la cadena como:

"8, 10, 13 y del 15 al 20, 23, 25, 27 y del 30 al 35, 45, 67 y del 69 al 70 y del 72 al 73, 75, 77, 79, 81 y del 85 al 88 y 90"

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el código que hice, si alguien le sirve:

```
// tenemos los numeros a trabajar en un array
$arrNros = [1,2, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13];

echo implode(" ", $arrNros) . "<br>";

// creamos un array con el indice 0 (primer numero de $arrNros)
$cota0[] = $arrNros[0];
// obtenemos el primer número para compararlo
$primerNro = $arrNros[0];
//recorremos el array a trabajar
foreach ($arrNros as $nro) {
    //*** si el primer numero es diferente al $nro entonce
    if ($primerNro != $nro) {
        // calculamos la diferencia entre el nro actual del indice y el primer nro
        $diferencia = $nro - $primerNro;
        // añadimos el $nro al array $cota0[]
        $cota0[] = $nro;
        // añadimos el $nro al array $cota1[] (es el numero final de la sucecion de números)
        $cota1[] = $primerNro - 1;
        // sumamos 1 para seguir comparando
        //(le sumamos la diferencia para obtener que el primernro de la siguiente secuencia no concecutiva)
        $primerNro = $primerNro + $diferencia + 1;
        //***si el $primerNro = al $nro entonces
    } else {
        // le sumamos 1 al $primerNro para obtener el siguiente numero consecutivo
        $primerNro = $primerNro + 1;
    }
}
// obtenemos el ultimo valor de la cadena y lo añadimos en array $cota1[]
$cota1[] = $arrNros[count($arrNros) - 1];

// terminado el foreach, obtenemos dos array: $cota0[],$cota1[]
// los indices de estos arrays se corresponden en su índice, ($cota0[3],$cota1[3])  =>  (x,y)
// este par de elementos es el intervalo de números encontrados en array inicial.
// habra pares que tengan el mismo número para ambos indices.

// imprimimos la cadena resultante
//obtenemos el total numero de valores cualquiera de los array resultantes
$size = count($cota0);

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    // si el intervalo tiene valores consecutivos (x,y)  donde y=x+1
    if (($cota0[$i]) + 1 == $cota1[$i]) {

        //si el intervalo es de +1 , imprimimos los dos valores separados por ","
        if ((count($cota0) - 1 != $i)) {
            // si el intervalos no es el ultimo intervalo imprimimos "," para añadirle el siguiente valor
            echo $cota0[$i] . "," . $cota1[$i] . ",";
            // si es el ultimo intervalo , no imprimimos la ","
        } else {
            echo $cota0[$i] . "," . $cota1[$i];
        }
    // si el intervalo (x,y) tiene valores diferentes, no consecutivos, imprimimo el intervalo separado por "al"
    } else if ($cota0[$i] !== $cota1[$i]) {

        if ((count($cota0) - 1 != $i)) {
            // imprime "," al final si no es el ultimo intervalo
            echo $cota0[$i] . " al " . $cota1[$i] . ",";
        } else {
            // NO imprime "," al final si es el ultimo intervalo
            echo $cota0[$i] . " al " . $cota1[$i];
        }

    // si el intervalo tiene valores iguales en el par (x,y) imprime cualquier de los dos valores en este caso (x)
    } else {

        if ((count($cota0) - 1 != $i)) {
          // imprime "," si no es el ultimo intervalo"  
          echo $cota0[$i] . ",";
        } else {
          // NO imprime "," si es el ultimo intervalo"  
            echo $cota0[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

obtenemos = 1,2,8,9,11 al 13

Te lo dejo comentado por si acaso no se comprende.

cambie la segunda parte para obtener el resultados que se busca en la pregunta inicial. (abrevie un poco).

```
$size = count($cota0);

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    
    $coma = (count($cota0) - 1 != $i) ? ",": "";

    // si el intervalo tiene valores consecutivos (x,y)  donde y=x+1
    if (($cota0[$i]) + 1 == $cota1[$i]) {
        echo $cota0[$i] . "," . $cota1[$i].$coma;
    // si el intervalo (x,y) tiene valores diferentes, no consecutivos, imprimimo el intervalo separado por "al"
    } else if ($cota0[$i] !== $cota1[$i]) {
        echo " y del ".$cota0[$i] . " al " . $cota1[$i] .$coma;
    // si el intervalo tiene valores iguales en el par (x,y) imprime cualquier de los dos valores en este caso (x)
    } else {
        echo $cota0[$i].$coma;
    }
}
```